# jmx файл не окрывается

Tags: юнит-тесты, jmeter

Установила последнюю версию jmeter apache-jmeter-2.13 Jmeter plugins JRE JAVA8.

```
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 697
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тексту `CannotResolveClassException` и `kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler` - не хватает плагина `DummySampler` в папке `lib/ext`.

Плагин `DummySampler` есть в стандартном наборе плагинов. Посетите http://jmeter-plugins.org/, скачайте `Standard Set` и установите в соответствии с инструкцией http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/:

1. Распаковать содержимое архива в папку с JMeter (в lib/ext появятся новые файлы).
2. Отредактировать конфигурационный файл `{%jmeter_bin%}/jmeter.properties` раскомментировав строку `jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true`.
3. Создать или дополнить конфигурационный файл `{%jmeter_bin%}/user.properties` строками, как сказано в инструкции.
4. Перезапустить JMeter.

Предполагаю, что поможет.

Бывает, что оперативной памяти не хватает для старта.

С другими причинами по которым файл jmx не открывает не сталкивался.